# How to create a ReplaySubject with RxCpp?

Tags: c++, rxcpp

In my c++ project, I need to create Subjects having an initial value, that may be updated. On each subscription/update, subscribers may trigger then data processing... In a previous Angular (RxJS) project, this kind of behavior was handled with ReplaySubject(1).

I'm not able to reproduce this using `c++ rxcpp lib`.

I've looked up for documentation, snippets, tutorials, but without success.

**Expected pseudocode (typescript):**

```js
private dataSub: ReplaySubject<Data> = new ReplaySubject<Data>(1);

private init = false;

// public Observable, immediatly share last published value
get currentData$(): Observable<Data> {

    if (!this.init) {
      return this.initData().pipe(switchMap(
        () => this.dataSub.asObservable()
      ));
    }
    return this.dataSub.asObservable();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for rxcpp::subjects::replay.
Please try this:

```cpp
    auto coordination = rxcpp::observe_on_new_thread();
    rxcpp::subjects::replay<int, decltype(coordination)> test(1, coordination);

    // to emit data
    test.get_observer().on_next(1);
    test.get_observer().on_next(2);
    test.get_observer().on_next(3);

    // to subscribe
    test.get_observable().subscribe([](auto && v)
        printf("%d\n", v); // this will print '3'
    });
```

Comment: Why do replaysubjects need this coordination when behaviorsubjects dont?